# How to access objects from NSMutableData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nsmutabledata

I have a NSMutableArray and a NSString . These two  are archived to NSData and add to a NSMutableData Object.

How can I access each data from NSMutableData Object.

```
NSData *dataArray= [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:mutableArray];
NSData *dataTouchedNumer=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:stringValue];                
NSMutableData *mutableData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
[mutableData appendData:dataArray];
[mutableData appendData:dataTouchedNumer];
```

Comment: Can you show us more of the code?

Comment: I just need how to access data from the mutableData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this the way you are showing. If you append two `NSData` objects together into a single mutable data object, there is no way to separate them later. Try this instead:

To archive the two objects:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = ... // your mutable array
NSString *stringValue = ... // your string

NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:mutableArray forKey:@"array"];
[archiver encodeObject:stringValue forKey:@"string"];
```

At this point, `data` contains the two objects. Do what you need with the data (save it for example).

To get your objects back:

```
NSData *data = ... // the archived data
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"array"];
NSString *stringValue = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"string"];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html), "`archivedDataWithRootObject:` returns an `NSData` object containing the encoded form of the object graph whose root object is given." So your `mutableData` object contains 2 such encoded object graphs. The question is what kind of data you want to read out of `mutableData`. It probably does not make much sense, to read simply all bytes with `[mutableData bytes]`, or part of it with `getBytes:length:` or `getBytes:range:`.